# Powershell ForEach Loop spitting out badly formatted samAccountName

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to take a list of account names from a group and then create a file in each of their home directories. But the problem I run into is everytime instead of getting the account (e.g. j.smith) I get @[h=samAccountName=j.smith] or something near that. I am at a lost to what I'm doing wrong. I'm a linux administrator who has been forced to work with PS for this project.

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Group" | select sAMAccountName |
ForEach-Object
{
Copy-Item
H:\test.txt H:\$_\test.txt
}
```

It ends up being `H:\@[samAccountname=j.smith]\test.txt` instead of `H:\j.smith\test.txt`

I'd very much appreciate help as I'm trying to complete this project by the weekend

Answer (score 1):

when you use select-object, it returned an array of objects. Use below instead:

```
$members = get-ADGroupMember
foreach ($member in $members){write-host $member.samAccountName}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that works with write-host but not Copy-Item. So I made a variable inside the foreach loop to store each user account then passed that to Copy-Item

Answer (score 0):

Using strongline's answer worked with write-host but not with Copy-Item it still spit out the same badly formatted @[samAccountName=j.smith]

What I did instead was

```
foreach($user in $Users)
{
$useraccount = $user.samAccountName
Copy-Item H:\test.txt H:\$useraccount\test.txt
}
```

And this does the trick. Thanks for the idea, strongline!